# Sage 300 V2020 development environment

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sage-erp, sage-300

I've inherited a couple of Windows Form Applications written in C# - MS Visual Studio 2012 that interact with Sage 2016. Both apps interact directly with Sage's SQL Server database. Additionally, one of them also uses Sage / ACCPAC classes. The customer wants to upgrade from Sage 2016 to 2020. Therefore I need to set-up a development / test environment containing Visual Studio, Sage 2020 and a test company database all on the same system. I've got the Visual Studio install, but how do I go about getting an eval of Sage 2020 and a test company database?

Comment: Did you contact the vendor?

Comment: Welcome to maintainance hell ... Does your company have any contracts with Sage? Maybe this is already included in some Support / Development / Partnership Plan?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll ask.